# CSS3 Border/gap around grids

Tags: css

What code do I need to add to remove the gap between grid items and the edge of the browser window? I'm new to grids and CSS, so go easy on me.

I don't want the white border around the grid;
https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/YrpqGP

```
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
}

.wrapper > div{
    background:#ee0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code snippets, so you will answers

Comment: use css reset. http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: Added code pen for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as putting this piece of code in you css fie.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Working snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: #ee0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, nam.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quia.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, nam.
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, quia.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If that worked mark your question as solved. So that someone in future struggling with same issue can easily resolve his kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code to your css file :

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

It will remove that space around.

Comment: Thank you very much